# Is it normal practice to use classes inherited from EventArgs as parameters

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Is it normal practice to use classes inherited from  EventArgs as parameters in methods or i should make Interface.
For example:

```
public class EvArgsTest : EventArgs
{
  public string Test { get { return "test"; } }
}

public foo()
{
   zoo(new EvArgsTest());
}

public zoo(EvArgsTest tr)
{
   Console.WriteLine(EvArgsTest.Test());
}
```

Is it good style?
(Sure i in case if i am already using EvArgsTest for events)

Comment: No this not good style. EventArgs are what the name implies; arguments for events. Why would you want to use it this way when you can implement classes with the same functionality without inheriting from EventArgs just as easily?

Comment: I have implemented and i am using it for events now... So i think: to make new class or use exesting

Comment: I'd strongly advise to make a new class.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bad practice!

`EventArgs` are meant to be use with events.

From MSDN

> EventArgs class represents the base class for classes that contain event data, and
>   provides a value to use for events that do not include event data.

I don't understand why you need to pass an object that inherit EventArgs to a method..

Create your own class or add more argments to methods